# Binding selected values of Combobox to subprogram

Tags: python, tkinter

### My code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

win = tk.Tk()

def assign():
    value = number.get()
    
    if value == 'op1':
        label = tk.Label(win, text = number)
        label.grid(column = 1, row = 0)

number = tk.StringVar()
box = ttk.Combobox(win, textvariable = number, state = 'readonly')
box['values'] = ('op1','op2','op3')

box.set('op2')

box.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

box.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', assign())


win.mainloop()
```

### Explanation: this is how I think my program works.

`box`, which is the `Combobox`, has assigned a `textvariable` named `number` that, I **suppose**, takes the values of `box`, that is, `('op1', 'op2', 'op3')`. `box` is then binded to a subprogram called `assign()` which will retrieve the value of `number` and set it equal to `value`. If `value` is equal to `'op1'`, the subprogram will create and grid a label called `label` that will display the text  `'Hello'`. Unfortunately, this doesn't work. In other words, my **objective** is to, when the user selects one of the values given in `box['values']`, `assign()` runs and, If the codition is met, display `label`.

### Output:

[image: output]

As you can see, even though I selected `'op1'`, `label` isn't displayed next to `box`.

Comment: Please let me know If you need more info.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5767228/7432

Comment: It should be `def assign(event):`.

Comment: Let me modify. One minute.

Comment: @CoolCloud Yes, it works!

Comment: @Nameless This was corrected in the code posted below already :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to remove the `()` while using `bind` to avoid function call, then create a label outside functions and then update it from the inside using `config`, like:

```
label = tk.Label(win)
def assign(event):
    value = number.get() # Get the value
    
    if value == 'op1':
        label.config(text=number) # Update the text
        label.grid(column = 1, row = 0)

box.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', assign) # Remove the ()
```

This way you don't rewrite the labels and just update the labels with new values.

But I think there is no use of `StringVar` here, just remove it and use `box.get()` to get the value from the combobox. So according to me the best practice would be:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

win = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(win) # Create this outside of function

def assign(event):
    value = box.get() # Get value from combobox
    
    if value == vals[0]: # Check the selected item with the values tuple
        label.config(text=value) # Update the text of label
        label.grid(column=1,row=0)

vals = ('op1','op2','op3') # Tuple of values
box = ttk.Combobox(win,values=vals,state='readonly') # Add value option
box.current(1) # Set the second item as current value
box.grid(column=0,row=0)

box.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', assign)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: @Nameless What do you mean did not work, explain what you got. Also, I have updated the answer, take a look now.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an error. When I select `'op1'`, `label` isn't displayed. Would you like me to post an image of the code written and the output?

Comment: @Nameless Which example are you trying, the second one?

Comment: Yes, the second one.

Comment: @Nameless I have tried it out and I get the output as op1 when first item is selected, perhaps a screenshot might help.

Comment: @Nameless Yes that would help too.

Comment: Did it. Is that enough?

Comment: I have a question. What's the different between `box.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', assign)` and `box.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', assign() )`

Comment: @Nameless As said in the answer, if you use `()`, you are calling the function directly, but you dont want to call it, you only want it to get called when you select something and tkinter handles that, so just give the function name to tkinter without `()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

win = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(win)  # Create this outside of function


def assign(event):
    value = box.get()  # Get value from combobox

    if value == vals[0]:  # Check the selected item with the values tuple
        label.config(text=value)  # Update the text of label
        label.grid(column=1, row=0)
    elif value == vals[1]:  # Check the selected item with the values tuple
        label.config(text=value)  # Update the text of label
        label.grid(column=1, row=0)
    elif value == vals[2]:  # Check the selected item with the values tuple
        label.config(text=value)  # Update the text of label
        label.grid(column=1, row=0)


vals = ('op1', 'op2', 'op3')  # Tuple of values
box = ttk.Combobox(win, values=vals, state='readonly')  # Add value option
box.current(1)  # Set the second item as current value
box.grid(column=0, row=0)

box.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', assign)

win.mainloop()
```